# PHP delete images in unknown subdirectories

Tags: php, delete-file, directory

I'm looking for a way to delete images older than 30 days in randomly named folders.

I have the following directory structure on my server:

```
mainDirectory (folder)
  imagedeletescript.php (script)
  images (folder)
    uploads (folder)
      randomNamedFolder (folder)
      randomNamedFolder (folder)
      randomNamedFolder (folder)
      randomNamedFolder (folder)
      etc.
```

This is my imagedeletescript.php:

```
<?
$days = 30;
$dir = dirname ("/images/uploads");

$nofiles = 0;

    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (( $file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
        if ( $file == '.' || $file == '..' || is_dir($dir.'/'.$file) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ((time() - filemtime($dir.'/'.$file)) > ($days *86400)) {
            $nofiles++;
            unlink($dir.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    echo "Total files deleted: $nofiles \n";
}
?>
```

The script above will delete the randomNamedFolders that are older than 30 days in the uploads folder and that is not what I want.

How can I get the script to scan all the randomly named folders inside the uploads folder and delete all the images older than 30 days inside the randomly named folders?

Comment: Are all folders in uploads randomly named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to implement a recursion. You can scan for all the directories and sub directories and even deeper directories.

```
<?php
     $days = 30,$deleted = 0;
     function delete_old_files($dir) {
       global $days,$deleted;
       if(!is_dir($dir)){
         return;
       }
       $files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dir));
       foreach($files as $file) {
         $path = $dir.'/'.$file;
         if(is_dir($path)){
            //the current file is a directory, re-scan it
            delete_old_files($path);
            continue;
         }
         if(time() - filemtime($path) > $days * 86400){
           unlink($file) ? ++$deleted : null;
         }
       }
       return $deleted;
     }
     //now call this function
     delete_old_files("/images/uploads");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and [`stat()`](http://php.net/stat):

```
$days = 30;
$images = glob('/images/uploads/{*.png,*.jpg,*.bmp}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $stats = stat($image);
    if ($stats[9] < (time() - (86400 * $days)) {
        unlink($image);
    }
}
```

This looks for files (regardless of theirs depth) with the extensions `.png`, `.jpg`, or `.bmp` in the folder `/images/uploads` and checks if they're older than 30 days.

**Hint:** Though not directly connected to your issue: As pointed out by @D4V1D, always use curly brackets (`{}`) for your conditions even if there's only one condition in this situation.

Comment: You should use curly braces for your condition even if there's only one statement.

Comment: @D4V1D: Can you clarify the comment? What should be changed in your opinion?

Comment: `if ($stats[9] < (time() - (86400 * $days)) {}`<-- here.

Comment: @D4V1D: Done, though not necessary ;)

Comment: Not necessary but bad practice otherwise.

Comment: @D4V1D: Updated the answer and added a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replicate your `while` loop inside main `loop`, or you can use either `scandir()` or `glob()` in this way:

```
(...)    
while (( $file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {
    if ( $file == '.' || $file == '..' || is_dir($dir.'/'.$file) ) {
        continue;
    }

    $curDir = "$dir/$file";
    foreach( scandir( $file ) as $rndFile ) {
        if ( $rndFile == '.' || $rndFile == '..' || is_dir("$curDir/$rndFile") ) continue;
        if ((time() - filemtime("$curDir/$rndFile")) > ($days *86400)) {
            $nofiles++;
            unlink($dir.'/'.$file);
        }
   }
}
(...)
```